# Multiple shopping cart view in cart page

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I want to show `shopping cart view` in different style on mobile view .
how can I clone `shopping cart view` to show it on another format like `unformatted list` or what is your approach to show this views on mobile on none table format ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_responsive_ui as a starting point. This module uses different displays (no tables) for the cart and checkout views.

Comment: I think this module override shopping cart form views, i want to have another shopping cart form to display it on mobile device